# Can Someone Please Explain Absolutely-Positioned Flex Children

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm reading the documentation for flex https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items and I would like someone to please visually explain this to me.

Specifically this bit:

The static position of an absolutely-positioned child of a flex container is determined such that the child is positioned as if it were the sole flex item in the flex container, assuming both the child and the flex container were fixed-size boxes of their used size. For this purpose, a value of align-self: auto is treated identically to start.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45784341/3597276

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that an absolutely positioned child in a flex container should still follow alignment rules like `justify-content`, `align-items` and `align-content`.
However, it will not care about other children in the flex container.

Also read https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/absolute-positioned-children