# Centering absolutely positioned element in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-grid

On Mozilla this pen works. But when I switch to Chrome it breaks.

It's just me or something is wrong with browsers?

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: beige;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.container h2 {
  position: absolute;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>TEXT</h2>
</div>
```

[codepen LINK](https://codepen.io/Konrad001/pen/zdWZLG)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that Chrome has deviated from spec guidance on this issue.

The `justify-self` and `align-self` properties *should* work on an absolutely-positioned child element of a grid container.

> [**9.2. With a Grid Container as
>   Parent**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#static-position)
>
> An absolutely-positioned child of a grid container is out-of-flow and
>   not a grid item, and so does not affect the placement of other items
>   or the sizing of the grid.
>
> The static position of an absolutely-positioned child of a grid
>   container is determined as if it were the sole grid item in a grid
>   area whose edges coincide with the padding edges of the grid
>   container.
>
> *Note that this position is affected by the values of `justify-self`
>   and `align-self` on the child.*

So, Firefox seems to have this right.

For other centering options see this post:

- [Centering in CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45536537/3597276)

Answer (score 0):

`position: absolute` is throwing off Chrome (tested on v62). It seems Firefox interprets the `justify-self` and `align-self` attributes as overrides, while Chrome doesn't, hence the different behavior.

Just remove `position: absolute` and it works.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vJRmNR

Comment: So its basicly a chrome bug? I need to keep the absolute positioning in this case :(

Comment: @KonradAlbrecht I'm not sure why, you're telling the element to be positioned absolutely, but you're providing no other positioning information (like `top` or `left`). `justify-self` and `align-self` do the _same thing_ as `position: absolute`, so they conflict. The difference between browsers is how they handle the conflict. Perhaps you can absolutely position the container div instead.